# Reference to two assemblies, each one with reference to the another assembly but with different version

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, .net-assembly

In a ASP.Net application I have a class.

This class need reference to two assemblies that I wrote before:

```
FMDriver.dll
MyWorldObj.dll
```

Each one of those assemblies use `MySql.Data.dll` but with different versions.

If I add references from my new project (with `Copy Local = true`) to those two assemblies I get errors because `MYWorld.dll` can't find `MySql.Data.dll`. Maybe that's because it uses an older version af the MySql library? If I remove reference to `FMDrvier.dll` MyWorldObj work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Binding Redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) before to get all referenced assemblies to use one version. Not sure if this solution will work for you.

You essentially provide an old version and a new version:

```
<bindingRedirect  
   oldVersion="old assembly version"
   newVersion="new assembly version"/>
```

Then make sure the new version `.dll` is in the bin if your project.

Otherwise it looks like time to upgrade the assembly to use the same version.

Comment: IN the end, I upgraded other libraries to work woth the past MySQL.Data.dll